# Google Scripts: Concatenating Form Responses

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm completely new to the google scripting language. I've been following a tutorial (http://www.jessespevack.com/blog/2016/2/9/turn-a-google-form-response-into-a-calendar-event) trying to convert a leave form response to a calendar event. I'm trying to find a way to concatenate a number of fields into a single attribute, but I haven't been able to find a way to achieve this.

The tutorial includes this section:

```
  //a mapping of form item titles to sections of the 
  //calendar event
  formMap : {
    eventTitle : "",
    startTime : "",
    endTime: "",
    description: "",
    location: "",
    email: "",
  },
```

After each attribute ("eventTitle", "startTime" etc) it requires me to list a field name from my form ("First Name", "Last Name") etc between the quotes. Using one field in each works just fine, but I need to concatenate two fields into some attributes (such as "First Name" + "Last Name"), but all traditional methods I know of don't work.

Combining questions (ie a single name field) isn't an option as there's more data I need to collect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have extra form items/fields that you want to include in a new event. However, since the `createEvent()` has limited parameters - you would like to combine extra form information into one of the [createEvent() parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)) (e.g, event "description")?

```
// Add the extra form fields into your form map
formMap : {
  eventTitle : "",
  startTime : "",
  endTime: "",
  firstName: "", //to be concatenated into description or other parameter
  lastName: "", //to be concatenated into description or other parameter
  description: "",
  location: "",
  email: "",
},


// Add the new form items/fields to the `switch` statement
function getFormResponse() {
  var firstName, lastName;
...

  for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {

...

  switch (thisItem) {
    case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
      eventObject.title = thisResponse;
      break;
    case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
      eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
      break;
    case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
      eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
      break; 
    case GLOBAL.formMap.firstName:
      firstName = thisResponse;
      break;
    case GLOBAL.formMap.lastName:
      lastName = thisResponse;
      break;
    case GLOBAL.formMap.description:
      eventObject.description = thisResponse;
      break;
    case GLOBAL.formMap.phone:
      eventObject.phone = thisResponse;
      break;
    case GLOBAL.formMap.email:
      eventObject.email = thisResponse;
      break;
    } 
  }

  //Once form responses are assigned, concatenate multiple items to eventObject.description
  eventObject.description += " with " + firstName + " " + lastName;

  return eventObject;
}
```

Use the [Addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment_2) to concat the form fields into one of the [createEvent() parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)):

```
//Once form responses are assigned, concatenate multiple items to eventObject.description
eventObject.description += " with " + firstName + " " + lastName;
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much!